# Is this problem calculable only due to the parameter choices?

Tags: self-study, random-variable, expected-value, sample, teaching

I am looking at a problem form Hogg, Tannis & Zimmerman (Ed. 10), and I am curious if the given problem is calculable (for an upper-level undergrad math/stats course) because of the choice of the parameters.

To respect the authors' copyright, I won't repeat the problem as written, but I will represent the key query:  $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. with a gamma distribution with parameters shape $k=1$ and scale $\theta=2$ (using the parameterization shown on the Wikipedia page).  Let $Y_1=\min(X_1,X_2)$ and $Y_2=\max(X_1,X_2)$ and $Z=\alpha Y_1 + \beta Y_2$.  Compute the expected value of $Z$.

My strategy would be to do the following:

1. Find the cdf $G_2(y)=P(Y_2 \le y) = F(y)^2$
2. Find the pdf $g_2(y) = G_2^\prime(y)$ (using $f(y) = F^\prime(y)$ and the chain rule)
3. Find $E(Y_2) = \int_{S_{Y_2}} y g_2(y)\ dy$
4. Repeat for $E(Y_1)$ using $G_1(y) = (1-F(y))^2$
5. Use the linearity of the expectation operator to find $E(Z)$.

Because I hoped to solve a more general version of the problem, I left the parameters as $k$ and $\theta$ in the gamma function (instead of using the proposed values).  This appears to result in a problem that cannot be easily calculated in terms of these parameters (or the size of the random sample, which I also left as an unspecified value $n$).

However, when you plug these given parameters into the gamma function, you get an exponential function.  And, the resulting formula is easily calculated for a sample (at least for size $n=2$).

Again, my query is if a general solution is possible (in terms of the given parameters and closed-form solutions) for specific parameters...or perhaps I am missing something in my approach that would simplify the process.

Comment: Quoting a textbook problem constitutes fair use; it does not violate any (US) copyright law.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't demonstrate any more than you already know, but this approach might help confirm your suspicion that the parameter $k=1$ is special.  Along the way you might find some useful general shortcuts.

---

Let's begin far more generally: suppose only that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent with distribution functions $F_1$ and $F_2,$ respectively (which means for all real $x,$ $\Pr(X_i\le x) = F_i(x)$).  I will assume the expectations of the $X_i$ are known.

You can exploit $Y_1+Y_2 = X_1+X_2$ to express

$$E[Y_1] + E[Y_2] = E[X_1] + E[X_2]$$

and from this compute

$$\begin{aligned}
E[\alpha Y_1 + \beta Y_2] &= \alpha(E[Y_1] + E[Y_2]) + (\beta-\alpha)E[Y_2] \\&= \alpha(E[X_1]+E[X_2]) + (\beta-\alpha)E[Y_2].
\end{aligned}$$

**This reduces the problem to finding $E[Y_2].$**

The event $Y_2\le x$ is the event that both $X_i$ are less than or equal to $x,$ whence

$$F_{Y_2} = \Pr(Y_2\le x) = \Pr(X_1\le x)\Pr(X_2\le x) = F_1(x) F_2(x)$$

due to the independence of the $X_i.$

Consequently

$$\begin{aligned}
E[Y_2] &= \int_{-\infty}^0 F_{Y_2}(y)\mathrm{d}y + \int_0^\infty 1-F_{Y_2}(y)\mathrm{d}y\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 F_1(y)F_2(y)\,\mathrm{d}y + \int_0^\infty 1-F_1(y)F_2(y)\,\mathrm{d}y. 
\end{aligned}$$

When at least one of the $X_i$ has nonnegative support (as in this question), the first integral is zero.  Thus, **whatever the answer might be is tantamount to evaluating the second integral.**  That's hard to do when the $F_i$ are incomplete Gamma functions--I don't know of any theory of integrals of products of those functions--but there is an easy special case: when they are exponentials (incomplete Gamma functions with parameter $1$).

Let's deal with that.  Let the scale factors be $\theta_i,$ so that $F_i(y) = 1 - \exp(y/\theta_i)$ for all $y\ge 0.$  Plugging into the foregoing expectation formula gives

$$\begin{aligned}
E[Y_2] &= \int_{0}^\infty 1 - (1 - e^{y/\theta_1})(1 - e^{y/\theta_2})\,\mathrm{d}y = \int_0^\infty e^{y/\theta_1} + e^{y/\theta_2} - e^{y/\theta_1 + y/\theta_2}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&= \theta_1 + \theta_2 - \frac{\theta_1\theta_2}{\theta_1+\theta_2}.
\end{aligned}$$

Since $E[X_i] = \theta_i,$ the answer is

$$E[\alpha Y_1 + \beta Y_2] = \beta(\theta_1+\theta_2) - (\beta-\alpha)\left(\frac{\theta_1\theta_2}{\theta_1+\theta_2}\right).$$

---

**There are other special cases you might enjoy exploring:** for *positive integral* shape parameters $k,$ repeated integration by parts ($k-1$ times) establishes that the incomplete Gamma functions $F_i$ are polynomials times an exponential.  This makes the integrand $1-F_1(y)F_2(y)$ a polynomial (usually of higher degree) times exponentials, which is elementary to integrate.  There will be many terms, though: when the shape parameters are $k_i,$ expect around $(1+k_1)(1+k_2)$ nonzero terms.

Comment: This approach with $Y_1+Y_2 = X_1+X_2$ is great (hadn't considered that nice trick)...but it does seem to limit a generalization of this problem to random samples of size $n=2$.  Thnx for confirming that this problem does have some very strong reliance on the parameter choice for the gamma distribution.

Comment: The (useful) generalization is that the expectation of the sum of all the order statistics equals the sum of the expectations.

Comment: My thought is that if the problem retains the r.v. $Z$ defined as the sum of the min and max, then the full ordering won't help there.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that $\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=1,\mathrm{scale}=\theta)$ is exponential, specifically $\mathsf{Expm}(\mathrm{mean}=\theta)\equiv\mathsf{Exp}(\mathrm{rate}=1/\theta).$

Using the CDF method, you can show that if
$X_1, X_2$ are IID $\mathsf{Exp}(1/\theta),$ then
$Y_1=\min(X_1,X_1) \sim \mathsf{Exp}(2/\theta),$ so that
$E(Y_1) =\mu_1 =\theta/2.$

Similarly but with a little more difficulty,
you can find $E(Y_2) = E(\max(X_1,X_2)) = \mu_2$ (in terms of $\theta).$

Finally, $E(\alpha Y_1 + \beta Y_2) = \alpha\mu_1 + \beta\mu_2.$

---

Here is a brief simulation with $\theta = 6, \alpha=5, \beta=10$ with sufficiently
accurate results (2 or 3 significant digits) that you can check each part as you go along.

```
set.seed(121)
th = 6;  alp = 5;  bet = 10
x1 = rexp(10^7, 1/6)
x2 = rexp(10^7, 1/6)
mean(x1);  mean(x2)
[1] 5.999339   # aprx E(X1) = 6
[1] 6.000077   # aprx E(X2) = 6

y1 = pmin(x1, x2)
y2 = pmax(x1, x2)
mean(y1);  mean(y2)
[1] 2.999401   # aprx E(Y1) = 3
[1] 9.000015   # aprx E(Y2) = 3 + 6 = 9

z = alp*y1 + bet*y2
mean(z)
[1] 104.9972   # aprx E(Z) = 15 + 90 = 105
```

*Note:* An intuitive answer to $E(Y_2)$ is that
that the min averages 3, then by the no-memory property of
exponential random variables, the max must be 6 greater on average, so $E(Y_2) = 3+6=9.$

Comment: Thanks for sharing this response.  I think you mean in the note that the max averages 3.  First, I'm uncertain how the no-memory applies here.  Also, it appears you've provided a general solution for $k=1$, but this doesn't address my initial query for a general solution w.r.t. the given parameters.  (This seems to confirm my impression that this problem is an artifact of a special set of parameters for the gamma function).

Comment: The min averages 3. Consider modeling the lifetime of a type of device. Each device is subject to potentially fatal events at a rate of $1/6$ per year or one every 6 years. Then a series system of two devices is hit a rate of $2/6=1/3$ per year or one every three years. So the avg of minimum is 3 yrs. By the no memory property the surviving device has an avg life of another 6 yrs so the max will avg 9 yrs. // Because you haven't shown much of a start on a solution I hoped my Ans would give you a start. //  I had NO plan to work the entire textbook problem for you. // Sorry if this not helpful.

Comment: No sure what is meant by "haven't shown much of a start on a solution" ...as the strategy in the original post does indeed produce the correct answer (for $k=1$ and $\theta=2$). Though, as noted, the query was about generalizing the problem (if possible).  Thnx for your response.